# Unable to find element using python3 selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Im trying to fill a textfield on a website. I've tried to find the element using the ID and xpath. Both return and error element not found. I can't seem to figure out why I can't find the element. The html can be found here https://pastebin.com/jTXR6uwL. The part I'm trying to retrieve is

```
<input value="" data-error="Name is required" id="first_name" type="text" name="first_name" 
class="form_item  is_required" placeholder="First Name">
```

I've tried using the following code but they all return an error. I got the xpath using google chrome dev tools.

```
first_text = driver.find_element_by_id('first_name')

first_text = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="first_name"]')

first_text = 
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[5]/div[2]/form/div[3]/span/input[1]')
```

All 3 return

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element
```

Can someone explain why I'm unable to find this element?

Comment: I copied the source HTML and it worked straight away with `elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="first_name"]')`. Are you sure you've moved to the appropriate site using `driver.get` beforehand?

Comment: have you checked if element is inside iframe or not?

Comment: I think they have some anti-bot measure, I can find elements outside of the form but anything inside of the form I'm unable to find